# app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I don;t understand why this error occur.I downloaded the Android 1.5.1 and having jdk 7 install but whenever I run an hello world application it does not debug and shows the following error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I don;t understand why this error occur and I run my old application project in this android studio it works but newly project can;t work

Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (Details)
Kindly solve my problem.I am beginner in Android

Comment: Update your android studio to the stable version and java as well to something like 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes that error is caused because your method count has exceed from 65K.

this worked for me:

in app/build.gradle add this line

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and in dependecies add

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much,Sorry for late reply but I do the same thing which you said above and it works